# Error al relacionar tablas con FOREING KEY MariaDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb

estoy creando 3 tablas pero al momento de importala en mariaDB me sale error,
las 2 primeras tablas se agregan pero la 3 no.

[image: Codigo sql]

[image: error en mariaDB]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto, pues como imagen es difícil reproducir tu ejercicio

Comment: Bienvenido AndriDev.... Por favor edita la pregunta y escribe el codigo con las herramientas que el sitio ofrece... por favor, date una vuelta por [ask] para mas informacion y de paso date un [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu primer `foreign key` de la tabla comentarios esta mal escrito, el problema se centra en un error de sintaxis:

tu código esta así:

```
foreign key(autor_id) references(usuarios(id))...
```

debería ser:

```
foreign key(autor_id) references usuarios(id)...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probaré.